# Is there any way to set & bypass default value to the captcha?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Currently i am want to automate the banking application (with the selenium web-driver) in which more use of captcha. i know very well captcha is used to prevent automation & there is one way to block the captcha functionality from testing environment & do the work.

But my Question is that, is there any way to set & bypass the default value to captcha, so that we can automate the captcha functionality without hiding the captcha code?

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: I can't see why is this selenium related?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to ask whoever wrote the banking application.

If it is possible for a user to bypass the captcha through the web front-end then webdriver should be able to automate it fairly easily. If it's not possible for a user to bypass it, then webdriver may be able to do something clever with javascript.  But it all depends on what the application allows.

If there are hidden inputs which can be used to bypass the captcha for example, then [WebDriver deliberately can't interact with them, but custom javascript can](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-why-is-it-not-possible-to-interact-with-hidden-elements). However the point of captchas is to make it impossible to for an automated script to get through, so no well-designed captcha would have such an obvious loophole.

Comment: I agree, any more info about "If it's not possible for a user to bypass it, then web-driver may be able to do something clever with javascript".

Comment: I'd also have to ask what you gain from automating it. You should try the CAPTCHA you are using is well tested.